# Dividing classes into smaller ones C++

Tags: c++, oop, coding-style

I've recently created a program that handles and manipulates images and converts them into ASCII versions. I put all of the code in one class, properly divided into functions. I organized the functions into groups (functions operating on the file, filters, image rotation, etc.).

And here is my question. How to separate these particular groups, so that all of this code does not sit in one class, but is more organized? I was thinking about a solution where I would extract the code into auxiliary classes, create the appropriate sub-objects in the main class, and access functions as follows:

```cpp
//main object (containing all of the picture info)
Image img("image.jpg");

img.filters.changeToGrayscale(); // filters, that is sub-object
                                 // containing "filter" functions
```

But I don't know if this is the optimal solution. Maybe some advice from more experienced coders? :P

EDIT: I know that I should divide it, but how to do it in c++?
If I want those smaller classes have access to members of the main class, I would have to mark them as `friend` classes and send main object instance to them to be able to do that. And idk if that is the best way of doing it.

Here is the code if you're interested: [github Ascii Generator](https://github.com/Billypl/Ascii-Generator)

Comment: Consider also to not force a class in your design without a precise reason, there are also free functions and namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

I think you already prepared your `Image` class to be divided into smaller classes. It is necessary to make one small class which will have just one responsibilty. E.g. `Filter` class
will just apply filters for your image, `File` class will be responsible just for managing file. `Position` class will be responisble just for flipping.

After doing this, your classes will correspond to the single responsibility principle of SOLID.
[Read more about single responsibility principle of SOLID here.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17100/clarify-the-single-responsibility-principle)

Sketch of your classes:

API of `ImagePosition` class would have methods:

```
void flipX();
void flipY();
void flipRight();
```

API of `FileManager` class would have:

```
void writeImageData(const char* filename);
void readImageData(const char* filename);
void printOperationStatus(bool isOperationSuccessfull, 
    const char* filename, std::string operationName);
```

API of `Filter` class  would have:

```
void grayscaleAvg();
void grayscaleLum();
void colorMask(float R, float G, float B);
```

API of `ASCII` class would have:

```
void printAscii(); 
void printAscii(std::string resultTextName);
```

API of `ImageHelper` class would have:

```
ImageType getFileType(const char* filename);
std::vector <Pixel> formatToPixels(uint8_t* data);
uint8_t* formatToUint8(std::vector <Pixel>& pixels);
```

Comment: Yeah, I get that. But how to do it? If I want those smaller classes to have access to members of the main class, I would have to mark them as `friend` classes and send main object instance to them to be able to do that. And idk if that is the best way to to that.

Comment: @Billy.pl sorry, I do not know C++. I just shared with thoughts how API of classes would look like.